# Error connecting to my AWS RDS in Singapore (Asia Pacific Region

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I keep running into this error while connecting to my newly built RDS MySQL instance

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   '****.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (60)

I wouldn't say I am an expert, as I have several EC2 instances running and able to connect. 
And I have all the security groups created and necessary permissions for inbound added accordingly. But i just quite connect to the  RDS instance. 
1. I have re-recreated with guide from AWS document, created new VPC group and dedicated DB security group. 
2. Gone through most of the responses from similar questions, and applied the suggested resolutions (which is adding own public IP in the inbound rules) etc..
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody. I was able to resolve the problem. The supported platform uses the EC2,VPC, so my AWS account is in the current region that does not use a default VPC. I dumped everything out, created VPC using wizard, then the security group. Then re-created the DB instance, assigned it the new VPC i re-created. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

1)
Make sure that the server is running

```
telnet ****.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com 3306
```

2) Make sure that the server is not bind to specific address.

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

3) Make sure that the IP address that you have added to security group is correct. Don't forget the /32 for a single ip. You can get IP address from

```
/sbin/ifconfig
```

4) Make sure that there are no firewalls on outbound traffic on the host from which you are trying to connect

Answer (score 0):

Does your RDS configured as publicly accessible? If not, you can only connect it within your VPC.